# how to get the email address and the user Id in fbml using cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, facebook

I have used one javascript function which is being called after login on facebook connect.

```
    var FB_API_KEY = "api key";
var FB_CHANNEL_PATH = "xd_receiver.htm";

FB.init(FB_API_KEY, FB_CHANNEL_PATH, {permsToRequestOnConnect : "email"});
FB.Connect.ifUserConnected(FB_ConnectPostAuthorization);

function FB_ConnectPostAuthorization() {

    var user_box = document.getElementById("user_id");
    user_box.innerHTML = 
    "<span>"
    +"<fb:profile-pic uid='loggedinuser' facebook-logo='true'></fb:profile-pic>"        
    +"Welcome , <fb:name uid ='loggedinuser' useyou='false'></fb:name>" 
    +"You are signed in with your facebook account"
    +"</span>";

    FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomTree();


    FB_RequireFeatures(["Api"], function(){
        var api = FB.Facebook.apiClient;
        var fb_uid = api.get_session().uid;

        $.post('/users/fb_login/', {'fb_uid': fb_uid}, function(response) {
            if (response != "yes") {
                api.users_hasAppPermission("email", function(result) {
                    if (!result) {
                        FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("email", redirect_to_done_page);
                    } else {
                        redirect_to_done_page()
                    }
                })
            } else {
                redirect_to_done_page()
            }
        });
    });       
}

function redirect_to_done_page() {
    window.location = "xyz";
}
```

I have added a facebook connect button which calls the above function.

I am only able to get the user name and profile pic in through fbml tags. How do I get the user email and user id.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get email through fbml, because with it you can just show it and there is no point.

Actually you need to have a PHP part of the FB API which you can help you with that task.

Although you can use this very good [plugin for CakePHP](http://www.webtechnick.com/wtn/blogs/view/229/CakePHP_Facebook_Plugin_Auth_Facebook_and_more). It's really easy to get it working and you can get the user's email for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my problem is we are using cake php version 2 and we are on tight schedule so dont have time to upgrade it now. :(

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the FB api,but I'd be surprised if they gave out emails. Oh... it's Facebook. I eat my words.